# Show that a sequence (($x_n, y_n$)) in $X \times Y$ is $e$-Cauchy if the component sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) are $d_X$-Cauchy and $d_Y$ -Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

How to solve this?

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be metric spaces and let $e$ be a product
metric on $X\times Y$.

Show that a sequence (($x_n, y_n$)) in $X \times Y$ is $e$-Cauchy if the component sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) are $d_X$-Cauchy and $d_Y$ -Cauchy, respectively.

Comment: By a product metric you understand any metric on $(X\times Y)$? Because, for example if $e((x,y),(x',y'))=d_x(x,x')+d_Y(y,y')$ the result follows immediately.

Comment: Yes, any metric.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no restrictions on the metric $e$ then the claim can be false, even when $Y=\{y_0\}$ is a one-point set. For instance, let $X$ be the real line, $e((x’,y_0),(x’’,y_0))=|x’-x’’|$ and $d_X(x’,x’’)=\operatorname{arctan}|x’-x’’|$ for each points $x$ and $x’$ of the space $X$.  For each $n$ put $x_n=n$. Then a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is $d_X$-Cauchy, but a  sequence $\{(x_n,y_0)\}$ is not $e$-Cauchy. As a natural restriction on the metric $e$ we can put a correspondence on slices: $e((x’,y), (x’’,y))=d_X(x’,x’’)$ and $e((x,y’), (x,y’’))=d_Y(y’,y’’)$ for each points $x$, $x’$, and $x’’$ of the space $X$ and each points $y$, $y’$, and $y’’$ of the space $Y$. Then $$e((x’,y’), (x’’,y’’))\le e((x’,y’), (x’,y’’))+
e((x’,y’’), (x’’,y’’))= d_Y(y’,y’’)+d_X(x’,x’’),$$

so the claim follows from triangle inequality.

Comment: I think the problem says you can use any metric that it is constructed by the two metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$ because $e$ is a product metric, thats the only restriction. Prove for some specific metric is easy. I stuck on the prove of the general case.

Comment: @rbd33 It seems the following. As I wrote above, in the general case the claim is false. Put $X=\Bbb R$, $Y=\{y_0\}$ a one-point set, $d_X(x’,x’’)=\operatorname{arctan}|x’-x’’|$, $e((x’,y_0),(x’’,y_0))=|x’-x’’|=\tan{ d_X(x’,x’’)} $ for each points $x$ and $x’$ of the space $X$.  For each $n$ put $x_n=n$. Then a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is $d_X$-Cauchy, but a  sequence $\{(x_n,y_0)\}$ is not $e$-Cauchy, although the metric $e$ is constructed from the metric $d_X$.